# Git clone command not showing the remote branchs

Tags: branch, git-clone

I have a remote git repo that has a master branch1 and branch2
when i perform a git clone,I am only able to see the master and the remote branches are missing.
What could be done to fix this issue ?

when i do `git branch -a`

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use `git fetch origin --all`

Comment: $ git fetch --all
Fetching origin


$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master

Comment: are you sure the branches exist on your remote?

Comment: Yes i can see that

Comment: I have migrated the code from svn to a repo in my local and pushed it to the git repo in remote. Both in remote and my migrated local version i see the branches and i am doing a synch from svn to these branches on a regular basis as the development is still happening in svn.

Comment: Only thing i am doubtful is  in the local repo while i initially pushed to remote after migration, i am seeing the branches in detached head state .Does that have something to do with this ? Anyhow when i access the remote repo through gitlab i can clearly see the remote branches along with the master.I have read all the available links in the net and i couldnt find a solution for this :(

Comment: git fetch origin <branch-name> then  git checkout -b <branch-name>